# Dml operation that depends of Set up operation salesforce

Tags: apex, future

I have to update owner of object (DML Operation )
but before i  must to insert PermissionSet
that given permission to user to be able to be the owner 
all of this happend in update Trigger ??
Do you have any idea how to do that 
**I will  appreciate your helps !!!!!!**

```
trigger ProjectUpdate on Project__c (after update) 
{
   for (Project__c project : Trigger.new) 
         {
             if(oldProject.Project_Manager__c != project.Project_Manager__c )
               {
                          1) insert permission  set 
                          2) update owner (update owner ) depends of insert permission                  
                }
         }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. You can't fire triggers if user permissions prevent an action before you even start the trigger transaction. How are you changing ownership?

Comment: See Edit ... i want to make DMl operation with Set up Operation

Answer (score 0):

By looking at what you trying to achieve it looks like you want to share records with different owners. In salesforce the way to achieve this is using sharing. What you need to do is make the Project object private in OWD and create apex sharing rule or custom apex sharing record to share records with the new owner.

To see how to create apex based sharing see below

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm